# Offline playback available through azure media services? Any idea?

Tags: azure, media-player, drm, playready

My scenario is, we want to build mobile Apps (iOS, Android and Windows,mac) which should be able to play protected DRM content as  offline play the protected content which was downloaded previously. What are our options with Windows Azure media?

I would like to use offline play back for playready enabled azure media services. Is it still possible or not? please advise.Thanks

Comment: This is an opinion-solicitation question (plus a broad question) with lots of potential solutions. Not a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but it is not a supported scenario for Azure Media Services. we only offer DRM solution for online streaming at the moment.

Cheers,
Mingfei Yan

Answer (score 0):

Azure Media Services now supports offline playback scenarios. Offline Fairplay via Apple offline HLS is supported. AMS also provides persistent PlayReady and Widevine licenses for offline playback.